# Большая задержка при отправке формы через SMTP

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, phpmailer

Сайт wp + woocommerce. Поставил плагин WP Mail SMTP. После сабмита формы проходит по меньшей мере 40 секунд, затем происходит переадресация на страницу с благодарностью. Без плагина форма уходит быстро. Пробовал отправку через phpMailer. Ситуауция такая же. В чем может быть проблема?

Для уточнения. На сайте есть форма, которая обрабатывается внутренним обработчиком woocommerce. А есть формы, которые находятся в сплывающих модальных окнах - у них свой обработчик. В обоих случаях отправка через SMTP происходит крайне медленно.

Comment: smtp сервер, через который отправляете письма, видимо работает с такой скоростью.

Comment: Загадками говорите. 1. А письма уходят? 2. А без плагина - уходят? 3.Плагин имеет штук 5 настроек способа отправки, какой используете? 4. PhpMailer пробовали в плагине или отдельно класс добавили?

Comment: "такая же" - это какая именно из 2х описанных?

Comment: @KAGGDesign 1) письма уходят 2) без плагина уходят гораздо быстрее, но не на все почтовые ящики доходит письмо 3) Использую свои настройки с почтового ящика на хостинге (smtp.spaceweb.ru, порт 25, логин и пароль как положено) 4) phpMailer подключаю отдельно

Comment: Раз зависает PhpMailer, значит, неправильно настроен почтовый сервер. Не все доходят сообщения, потому что не настроен spf и dkim, скорее всего